# Greenworks 60V Pro Platform batteries: the 2.0, 2.5, & 3.0 Ah EACH contain (15) 3.6 V cells. How is this possible?

Tags: batteries

According to the specifications provided with Greenworks 60V Pro Platform batteries, the 2.0 Ah, 2.5 Ah, & 3.0 Ah **each** contain (15) 3.6 V cells.

How is this possible?

Greenworks 60V pro battery=LB602
Greenworks 60V pro battery=LB6025
Greenworks 60V pro battery/LB603
[EACH CONTAIN #15 3.6V LI CELLS]

Comment: The nameplate voltage is in the fully charged condition; i.e. 4V/cell. If I measure my Greenworks 24V batteries, they are 24V fully charged, but normally lower, e.g.22V.

Comment: how is what possible?

Comment: Are you asking why different battery packs have different capacities or are you asking how 15 batteries in series adds up to the nominal 60V rating for the pack?

Comment: Neither: all are 60v. 2.0, 2.5 & 3.0 each contain the same (15) 3.7v cells. As such how can the (3) represent (3) different ah ratings. It appears that the battery circuitry (@ it alone) determines the ah/length of use. If so I would like a hack to specifically, modify the 2.0 to make it 3.0. (is it a chip that controls the level of charge? i.e.: 2.0 charges to 80%; 2.5 charges to 90%; and 3.0 charges to 100% which in essence would increase use time). Note: the higher the ah the more $ unit costs.

Comment: You can buy different capacity cells, in the same case size. The higher capacity ones may be more expensive, or they may use thinner materials and have lower peak current ratings.

Answer (score 0):

The values will change but the principal is the same. When connecting batteries in series the cell  voltages will add. When connecting them in parallel (must be same voltage) the current will add.  You can do series, parallel combinations.  Example 2 1A 3V batteries. In series you will get 6V att 1A. In parallel you will get 3V at 2A.